# Javascript simple tasks

Tags: javascript

So, my task is to sort an array in Javascript by one parameter - value. It is calculated via the `.map` method which applies a formula to some object parameters. `.map` is supposed to return an array so that I could use is for sorting, but somehow I get undefined. 
This Javascript task should be simple, yet I don’t get it!
Here is the code

```js
function comparisonGame() {
  var peopleArr = [
    person_1 = {
      name: 'Nikita',
      age: 26,
      height: 182,
      value: 0
    },
    person_2 = {
      name: 'Pasha',
      age: 28,
      height: 193,
      value: 0
    },
    person_3 = {
      name: 'Olexey',
      age: 31,
      height: 168,
      value: 0
    }
  ];
  var transformendArr = [];

  function compare(value_1, value_2) {
    if (value_1 < value_2) {
      return 1;
    } else if (value_1 = value_2) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  transformendArr = peopleArr.map(function(age, height) {
    return this.value = this.age * 5 + this.height;
  });
  var sortedArr = transformendArr.value.sort(compare);
  return this.sortedArr[0].name;
}
alert(comparisonGame() + ' is a winner!')
```

Comment: `if (value_1=value_2)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: are you sure about the assignments inside of the array literal. it creates global variables in non strict mode.

Comment: `transformendArr.value` is undefined, that is caused because Arrays don't have `value` property. 

`value_1 = value_2` is not comparing, instead assigning.

Also take into account that assignments inside the array literal, will create a non strict global variable.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools step through the code and you'll be able to fix it

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I was wrong on multiple things.

Actually, You have multiple problems here.

1. `if (value_1 = value_2)` is not a comparison operation. you need to have two `=` signs to compare them. (This is removed by step 2).
2. You are returning the wrong number when comparing `value_1` to `value_2`. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), to compare numbers you need to use this.

   ```
   function compareNumbers(a, b) {
      return a - b;
   }
   ```
3. You can reuse `peoplearr` for your `.map` and `.sort` operations. Your `.map` call is incorrect. It should look something like this: `.map(x => x.value = x.age * 5 + x.height);` where `x` is each item in the array.

Overall your code should look similar to this.

```js
var peopleArr = [
  person_1 = {
    name: 'Nikita',
    age: 89,
    height: 164,
    value: 0
  },
  person_2 = {
    name: 'Pasha',
    age: 28,
    height: 164,
    value: 0
  },
  person_3 = {
    name: 'Olexey',
    age: 29,
    height: 164,
    value: 0
  }
];

function comparisonGame() {
  var equals = [];

  function compare(value_1, value_2) { // You don't really need this.
    return value_1.value - value_2.value; // Calling .sort() will do the same
  }

  peopleArr.map(x => x.value = x.age * 5 + x.height);
  peopleArr.sort(compare); // Can just call .sort()

  if (peopleArr[0].value === peopleArr[1].value) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  } else {
    return peopleArr[0].name + " is a winner";
  }
}
console.log(comparisonGame());

// Set Olexy's age equal to Pasha's 
// Remember the array is sorted, so [1] is Olexy now.
peopleArr[1].age = 28;

console.log(comparisonGame());
```

Comment: Thank you! I get it after all the helpful comments! And I wanted to ask, how can I effectively filter through the array looking for the equal values of value? My task is - make an alert if the result is a draw.

Comment: @NikitaKornienko I've added in some code to check if there is a tie. `isTie` will be `undefined` if there is no tie, which will cause `comparisonGame()` to return `peopleArr[0].name`. If there is a tie, it'll just return `"It's a tie!"`.

Comment: @NikitaKornienko Actually, I'm overthinking it. Just check if `peopleArr[0].value === peopleArr[1].value`. it if does, then there is a tie.  If it doesn't there somebody won.

Comment: ok, but what if I add more players? I’m trying to come up with a function that checks each and every array element on equality to others and I just fail.

Comment: @NikitaKornienko Why would you want to check every index if the definition of a tie is if `one` other person has the same value. In this case, it'll be the second person because `personArr` would be sorted. If you want a list of all people with the same `.value` I would ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
function comparisonGame() {
  var peopleArr = [
    {
      name: 'Nikita',
      age: 26,
      height: 182,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Pasha',
      age: 28,
      height: 193,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Olexey',
      age: 31,
      height: 168,
      value: 0
    }
  ];
  var transformendArr = [];

  function compare(value_1, value_2) {
    if (value_1 < value_2) {
      return 1;
    } else if (value_1 == value_2) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  transformendArr = peopleArr.map(function(person) {
    return Object.assign(person, { value: person.age * 5 + person.height });
  });
  
  transformendArr.sort(compare);
  return transformendArr[0].name;
}

alert(comparisonGame() + ' is a winner!')
```

You need to use `==` as a comparision. A aingle `=` is an assignment.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was most helpful and I learnt a new method too!

Comment: How can I make a draw in this task? Like if a ,value property was equal.

Comment: So you mean, in case the first two have the same value or if any two have the same value?

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> transformendArr.value.sort
> ```

`transformendArr` is an array.

`transformendArr.value` is undefined because arrays don't have values.

If you want to sort by the value property of each of the objects in the array, then your sort function needs to read the value property of `value_1` and `value_2` and you need to sort *the array* itself.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now.